# Seconed countable space is separable and first countable

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, solution-verification, alternative-proof, separable-spaces

Excuse me can you see this question 
Show that every seconed countable space is separable and first countable 
I tried on it but i am not sure , I get /
Let(X,T) be seconed countable space so there exist B={ Bn : n belong to N } s.t B countable base for X . 
When we write B={ B1,B2, ...} It doesn't mean that B is countably infinite it means that either for some n belong to N B={B1,B2, ... , Bn} or B empty or B is countably infinite .
If X non empty then B nonempty , if for some k belong to N Bk empty then {B1,B2, ... , Bk-1, Bk+1, ...} Is also basis for X so let us assume that Bn non empty for  all n 
Let xn belong to Bn ( note that by axiom of choice there is a function f:N _ union of Bn s.t xn = f(n) which is belong to Bn and A = { x1,x2,...} That is A is subset of X , obtaining by Chossing one element from each mber of Bn .
Here also it is quite possible that A is finite set . 
Claim : A is countable dense subset .
Clearly A is countable since | A | less than or equal | B | .
To prove A dense , take x belong to X and open set U containing x , now B is basis for X , U is an open set containing x but we have for any x belong to X there exist no belong to N s.t x belong to Bno , Bno subset of U and Bno intersection with A non empty .
Therefore x belong to closure of A implies X subset of clouser of A thus A closure = X . Thus A is countable dense subset of X therefore X is separable space .
To show that X is first countable . Let x belong to X , then choose the element of B that contains x , so Bx = { Bn : x belong to Bn } it is countable nhood base about x , thus X it is first countable .

Sorry for the rather long question. If is it rather confusing, let me know so I can clarify. I want to thank you in advance for taking the time to read this question.

Comment: You should use TeX to render math symbols so that your posts will be much more readable.

Comment: I don't know how i can do that ..

Comment: Hmmm, it does seem an oversight that the introductory tour doesn't mention MathJax, and although there is a link at the end to the Help Center, even that doesn't seem to mention MathJax either, not even if you click "View more" under the heading "Asking", and then click on "How do I ask a good question?"! How *do* newbies find out about MathJax? Is it like sex in Victorian England? :)

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is second countable, it has a countable base $\mathscr B$ for its topology.  Let  $(B_i)_{i\in\Bbb N}$ be an enumeration of the elements of $\mathscr B$.  For each $i$, choose $b_i\in B_i$.  Then $\{b_i:i\in\Bbb N\}$ is dense.  Thus $X$ is separable.

Secondly, since $\mathscr B$ is countable, each $x\in X$ has a countable neighborhood base.  Thus $X$ is first countable.